# Universal Windows App Store trial license time remaining incorrect

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app that's in the store and is set up as a 1 day free trial. When I download the app on a test machine, I see this in the Store listing, which is what I expect:
[image]

But, in the app, I'm using the Windows.Service.Store API and the StoreAppLicense  TrialTimeRemaining is returning this:

```
{10675199.02:48:05.4775807}
    Days: 10675199
    Hours: 2
    Milliseconds: 477
    Minutes: 48
    Seconds: 5
    Ticks: 9223372036854775807
    TotalDays: 10675199.116730064
    TotalHours: 256204778.80152154
    TotalMilliseconds: 922337203685477
    TotalMinutes: 15372286728.091293
    TotalSeconds: 922337203685.47754
```

This doesn't match at all. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: My colleage has replied you on your msdn thread, please give the code a try first so that we can understand it better.

Comment: Thanks. The ExpirationDate property is correct, so i can use that instead to display time remaining to my users. Seems like maybe there’s a bug with the TrialTimeRemaining property?

Comment: Seems this is related to permission issue for this API. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense.trialtimeremaining) The TrialTimeRemaining property is intended to be used by developers who have configured their app as a usage-limited trial in Partner Center. Usage-limited trials are currently available only to some developer accounts in Xbox managed partner programs. And I believe your app may haven't registered in Xbox managed partner programs, which might cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from Microsoft responded to this question on the MSDN forums, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c2389bc-3c39-4b19-8b36-00d6bb018cb7/windowsservicesstore-trialtimeremaining-property-is-not-correct)

The Store API also has an `ExpirationDate` property, which has the correct value, indicating the expiration date/time of the trial. I can use this to determine the time remaining.

Still not sure why the `TrialTimeRemaining` property is incorrect, though.